# Closing the Remote Desktop Connection also makes teamviewer unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, teamviewer

I installed team viewer on my remote machine using RDP.

Why my teamviewer screen becomes unresponsive (sometime black) when i close the RDP session. When i reconnects RDP then teamviewer session also becomes active.

[image]

Comment: Teamviewer session is unresponsive I cannot do any thing on my remote machine until I reconnected it with remote desktop in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This is because once you close the remote desktop connection, windows basically 'stops' the running graphical system for that user.

One way of fixing this would be to connect to the running console and login as if you were locally there - you could use vnc or dameware for this. Then just close them don't log off.

The difference is when you close RDP it ends the active session, but vnc and dameware won't.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for some workaround e.g. group policy etc. which let me to continue with the graphical system, if any.